# Include related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using Ef Core, how can I include an object that is not directly defined in table?

Ex.:

```
Table1
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public Table2 Table2 {get;set;}
}

Table2
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}

    public int Table1Id {get;set;}
    public Table1 Table1 {get;set;}
}
```

query:

```
var items =
    table1DbSet
    .Include(x => x.Table2) ???
```

I need to return "Table1" objects, so starting from table2 is not an option.
It is something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T2.TABLE1ID = T1.ID)
 WHERE ...
```

My actual example is a schedule table (table1) that generate an appointment(table2) register with its scheduleId. Then, I need to select schedule with appointment (if this exists).

Comment: Is it a one to many or a one to one relationship? Design your schema accordingly. Then map your entities according to the schema. Then execute your EF query with the `Include` clause.

Comment: It is a one to one. Its a legacy database, so I can't change tables and fields.

Comment: If it's one to one then the schema of the tables should have the same primary keys and that is also the FK of each table. Table1.PK = Table2.PK. If you do not have it mapped that way and you are using another column as the FK (example: Table2.PK = Table1.COLX) then you have a one to many relationship and you need to map it as such in EF *even if you always have a match of 1 to 1*. Once you fix your mappings then you can leverage EF correctly.

Comment: @Igor That's not true for EFC. One-to-one via separate FK is supported (it adds unique constraint).

Comment: @Beetlejuice `[NotMapped]` attribute prevents loading that property. `NotMapped` means "ignore, this is NOT tied to database in any way". Reference navigation property like this (and `ICollection` for one-to-many) in relationship principal do not introduce database column.

Comment: The tables are defined something like the SELECT above (it's not a really 1-1 relationship in database, but it is in business). How to map correctly to get that SELECT to work ?

Comment: By mapping that **navigation** property. How - by removing `[NotMapped]` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, it really works! Thanks.